# Clicking on Genymotion emulator freezes Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

I've been able to use the Genymotion emulator on Android Studio in the past. Today when I click on the Genymotion Device Manager the whole Android Studio freezes and I cannot do anything. I have to go into Windows Task Manager to shut Android Studio down.

Do I have to uninstall and reinstall Genymotion?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did need to uninstall and reinstall Genymotion to get it to work. The way Android Studio and Genymotion work, it took me an hour to do that. But now Genymotion does finally work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your computer need to upgrade RAM or CPU. Because Android Studio to slow with computer have a litle RAM

Comment: I don't think my RAM or CPU is the problem. I have plenty of RAM, and my CPU is top of the line.